# Architectural advice for Apache Camel and C

Tags: c, jms, apache-camel

I'm experimenting a bit with Apache Camel to propose it to my boss as an "ESB solution" which he is pushing for. Camel looks like a nice project, and a good way to keep away from more heavyweight stuff.

We've got a low-level layer implemented in C which listens to network events and is supposed to trigger some demo Camel route. Which is the best way to do such integration? I was thinking of JMS and [STOMP](http://stomp.github.com/) protocol, unfortunately its [C client library](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/STOMP/C) looks funny (you have to compile it on XCode, for one).

Have you got any alternatives to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resorted to using a Java Gateway which receives internal IPC calls using a native library provided by our vendor (HP Tandem NonStop mainframes) and translates them to JMS messages towards a demo broker running on my PC.

(My first step was actually to use HttpEndpoint).

Good advice also about low-level socket libraries in Java, we need some tuning to avoid weird behavior by standard network libraries on NonStop.

Answer (score 0):

there are several [components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) that allow Camel to interface with other (non-Java) applications.  off the top, [camel-jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html), [camel-jms](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html), [camel-file](http://camel.apache.org/file.html) and [camel-amqp](http://camel.apache.org/amqp.html) all provide this easily.  that being said, I'm not a C guy, so I'm not sure the best choice from that perspective...

If you are just preparing a demo, just use define an HTTP endpoint (using camel-jetty) to kick off your demo route.  As you progress, you can switch to something more robust (JMS, etc) for messaging between the two...

Answer (score 0):

Camel has some components ([camel-netty](http://camel.apache.org/netty.html), [camel-mina](http://camel.apache.org/mina.html)) which can provide lower level socket interaction. You may consider to use them to talk to your system.